# C# index out of range String Array and List<string>

Tags: c#, arrays

After trying a few error checking methods I have come to the conclusion I need help solving this problem.

How am I not catch this "index out of range" error. What can I do to avoid this problem in the future for good practice?

```
    public void loadFromFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog oFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        oFile.Title = "Open text file";
        oFile.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        oFile.FilterIndex = 1;
        oFile.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
        oFile.AddExtension = true;
        oFile.CheckFileExists = true;
        oFile.CheckPathExists = true;

        // Open and clean Duplicates
        String[] lines;
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();
        List<string> newlist = new List<string>();

        if(oFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Dummy file has 6 lines of text. Filename:DuplicatFile.txt
            // 3 duplicate lines and 3 not.
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(oFile.FileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            // Copy array to temporary array
            for (int index=0; index < lines.Length; index++)
            {
                // System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
                // Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
                if (lines[index].Length >= 0)
                {
                    temp[index] = lines[index];
                }
            }
            // Check for duplicates. If duplicate ignore if non-duplicate add to list.
            foreach (string line in temp)
            {
                if (!newlist.Contains(line))
                {
                    newlist.Add(line);
                }
            }
            // Clear listbox and add new list to listbox.
            lstBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string strNewLine in newlist)
            {
                lstBox.Items.Add(strNewLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
...
temp[index] = lines[index];
```

`temp` starts out with 0 size. Any index is out of range.

You can fix this by using `temp.Add`, to make the list grow dynamically:

```
temp.Add(lines[index]);
```

Comment: I should have known! Well done! I totally over looked that! Thanks for the advice I will try to stick to that method.

Answer (score 2):

Mud has the correct answer for the ArgumentOutOfRangeException.  You can simplify all the code in your if statement with Linq to be the following:

```
lines = File.ReadAllLines(oFile.FileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);    
lstBox.Items.AddRange(lines.Distinct().ToArray());
```

Comment: but if I was to do that how would it get rid of the duplicates?

Comment: The call to Distinct() will eliminate any duplicates lines.  Take a look at the documentation for more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx.

Comment: I like the idea of this, but it gives me a error.

"cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'object[]'"

Comment: Updated the answer to change the IEnumerable to an array.  It should work now.

Comment: That is still really short! Works pretty well! Thanks for helping with this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that the "lines" index is out of range - it's that the "temp" index is out of range... you have created a new List called "temp" but there is nothing in it..  it's length is 0!

Instead of copying from one index to another, you should use the .Add method:

```
temp.Add(lines[index])
```

of course... there better ways to duplicate an array, but this is closest to what you present above and answers your question directly.

Answer (score 1):

You get that error, because there is no elements at that index in list `temp`. (`temp` is empty). You can fill it with `temp.Add(value)`.

Another way to create temp list is to use `temp = newlist.ToList()`.

I would suggest to use LINQ: You can use

```
lstBox.Items.Clear();
foreach (var line in lines.Distinct())
    lstBox.Items.Add(line);
```

instead of all this code:

```
// Copy array to temporary array
for (int index=0; index < lines.Length; index++)
{
    // System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
    // Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
    if (lines[index].Length >= 0)
    {
        temp[index] = lines[index];
    }
 }
 // Check for duplicates. If duplicate ignore if non-duplicate add to list.
 foreach (string line in temp)
 {
   if (!newlist.Contains(line))
   {
       newlist.Add(line);
   }
 }
 lstBox.Items.Clear();
 foreach (string strNewLine in newlist)
 {
    lstBox.Items.Add(strNewLine);
 }
```

to simple:

Comment: I never knew about that one. Linq I dont use that often. I will try to use it more.

Comment: Linq is great thing, have a look at it. Life becomes more bright))